# PAM module for ssh: how to know if user is using key or password to authenticate

Tags: ssh, passwords, key, pam

I am writing a PAM module for ssh service. I would like to know how can I determine within the PAM module if user is using password or key to authenticate themself.

Thanks for your help and look forward for the answer please ! ! !

Comment: How the user authenticated from within sshd (ie; non-pam auth) doesn't seem to be passed to the pam session. However, you may be interested in pam ssh_agent_auth, it authenticates off of a key being present in a forwarded agent: http://pamsshagentauth.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

My reasonable *guess* is that sshd only uses pam_auth for keyboard-interactive login. For key-based login pam_auth wouldn't get called. It should be fairly easy to verify that by writing your own PAM module with logging or re-using verbose logging of some existing module.

Note that there is still PAM session, account etc. that I think sshd always uses.

I'm not sure why you need to detect what you want to detect. It should be easy to come up with a hacky way to do so if my guess is correct, but it seems to me you should clarify the question.

In fact, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318754/pam-module-pam-prompt-conversation-function-problem seems to confirm my guess. :)